# date relation between 2 tables

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables:

Budget, that include budget per month in € for each product (in each row the date is the last day of the month):

- 31/01/2023 product1 10000€
- 31/01/2023 product2 5000€
- 28/02/2023 product1 14000€
- 28/02/2023 product2 8000€
- ...

Sales, that include sales for each day for each product:

- 06/01/2023 product1 1000€
- 07/01/2023 product1 500€
- 07/01/2023 product2 40€
- ...
- 12/02/2023 product1 700€
- 15/02/2023 product2 80€
- ...

How do I correlate the two tables so that I can compare sales and budget for each month?
I've tried to create a relationship between the 2 date columns but I get an error regarding cardinality

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have the two tables correlated is to have a Dimension table for the Date. Basically, you create a Date Dimension table which has unique values of dates and use that table to connect both of the Budget and Sales Tables.

By this means you can compare both of your sales and budget data using a clustered column chart, with the X axis from the Dimension Date table and the Y-axes from the Sales and Budget Tables

Additionally, you can create a Dimension Table for the Products also with additional information regarding the Products and have them included in your analysis.